# UTF-8 Display for HTML

Tags: html, encoding, utf-8

I have some special characters in UTF8 format which I want to display. First I tried to read the origin (JSON) as UTF8 having also any kind of UTF8 meta tags in the header:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/json; charset=utf-8" />
```

As this did not work, I transfered the special characters to HTML syntax and tried (with and without the UTF-8 headers) to get it displayed. But somehow I even do not get this. Here is the text I can add in a simple HTML file, which is then not displayed correctly.

```
It's Possible! &#65533; Our Experiences
```

I also tried this page with the ISO-8859-1 charset, but this does not work as well. I hope someone can help me.

Thanks,
Katja

Comment: That is not UTF-8. That's an HTML entity. How does it "not display correctly"?

Comment: When I put this as it is into my HTML page, e.g. in the body, then it is still displayed as &#65533; and not as special ? sign. If I use the original special ? sign, then it is displayed as "not displayable item, meaning a weired looking question mark for any special character. The ? as &#65533; is just an example. Would I need any HTML-Tag or anything around that so it is displayed as it should be?

Comment: If you put `&#65533;` into HTML and it displays as &#65533;, you have not actually put `&#65533;` into your HTML but `&amp;#65533;`. In other words, you have HTML-entity encoded the HTML entity. You're escaping one time too many somewhere. But again, as stated below, the data seems to be already screwed up. It's inconceivable why you have HTML entities in JSON, and even more inconceivable why you have the HTML entity for a broken character encoding in your JSON.

Comment: It looks my JSON had not been UTF8 ... (at least the latest versions ...) Sorry and thanks for the hints! I have searched tooo long for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `&#65533;` is literally the text you get in your JSON, there's nothing you can do. `&#65533;` is the HTML entity for the UNICODE REPLACEMENT CHARACTER �, i.e. the Unicode character which is inserted when something went wrong.

This points to the original text having been screwed up by the originator. There's no way to know what that character was supposed to be before it screwed up and got replaced by �.

Comment: I know what is meant originally. Originally I have the "?" sign in my JSON, but as it is not displayed correctly I tried other ways. I converted Text to HTML where I got that code from. But even when I used this code im my HTML body, it is displayes as pure text and not as special ? sign.